# Why does count variable does not count recursivley?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

My script has to decompress compressed files. I'm trying to do that if a target file is a folder -> decompress everything inside it.

This is my code:
*Update - I have fixed it by shellcheck

```
#!/bin/bash
#unpack
INPUTS=$@
R=false
V=false
declare -a TOTALCOUNT
toecho=0
declare -a FILES

function decompress_by_file_type()
{
    case $(file --mime-type -b "$file") in
        application/zip) unzip -oq "$file" 
                 echo 0 ;;
        application/x-bzip2) bunzip2 -dkfq "$file"
                 echo 0 ;;
        application/gzip) uncompress -fq "$file" 
                 echo 0 ;;
        application/gzip) gunzip -q "$file"
                 echo 0 ;;
        inode/directory) 
                 decompress_all_in_folder ;;
    esac
}

function decompress_all_in_folder()
{
    cd "$file"
    for file in *
    do
        if [ "$(decompress_by_file_type)" == 0 ]; then
            TOTALCOUNT+=(1) 
        fi  
    done
}

function get_user_input()
{
    for input in $INPUTS 
    do
        case $input in
            -r)
                R=true ;;
            -v) 
                V=true ;;
             *)
                FILES+=("$input") ;;
        esac
    done

    for file in "${FILES[@]}"
    do  
        case $(file --mime-type -b "$file") in
        inode/directory) 
                 decompress_all_in_folder ;;
        *)
                if [ "$(decompress_by_file_type)" == 0 ]; then
                    TOTALCOUNT+=(1) 
                fi ;;
        esac
    done
}

function calculate_arr_values()
{
    get_user_input
    for i in "${TOTALCOUNT[@]}"
    do
        toecho=$((toecho+i))
    done
    echo "$toecho"
}


echo "Decompressed $(calculate_arr_values) archive(s)"
```

Actually - it does decompress every file. But the output count is incorrect for some reason. 
The output (the last echo) shows me only the number of the files which were decompressed - only of the first folder. 
As you can see, I do count on every part. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you quoting variables inside `$((...))`?

Comment: Passing `$file` as an argument to the two `decompress_*` functions doesn't do anything; both treat `$file` as a *global* variable.

Comment: You are calling your functions in `$(..)` which creates a subshell. All variable modifications in such a subshell are lost. Either rewrite to avoid subshells, or rewrite to print and capture all relevant information for the parent shell

Comment: You never increment `TOTALCOUNT`, all you do is add new array elements. So it ends up being an array like `(1 1 1 1 1 1...)`

Comment: @Barmar The array is summed up in `calculate_arr_values` -- very inefficient but would work when fixing the subshell problem.

Comment: Use `return 0` instead of `echo 0`, and then use `if decompress_by_file_type $file`

Comment: @Socowi I see. But since all the array elements are just `1`, that could just be `${#TOTALCOUNT[@]}`

Comment: Paste your code into https://www.shellcheck.net/ -- there are *lots* of errors to correct.

Comment: @glennjackman fixed by your advised - please have a look

Comment: @thatotherguy can you please write an example? I'm really new to it

Comment: The use of `$INPUTS` is unfortunate (exposes you to string-splitting/glob-expansion/related bugs). Where's that value supposed to come from? Generally, you're much better off accepting your inputs somewhere that treats each element as a separate string, such as on the function's argument list.

Comment: BTW, note that `function myfunc() {` is combining the legacy ksh syntax of `function myfunc {` and the POSIX sh syntax of `myfunc() {` in a way that's compatible with neither legacy ksh *nor* with POSIX sh. Consider sticking with one or the other (personally, I'd suggest the POSIX syntax, a recommendation seconded by http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete).

Comment: As another aside, it's a better habit to use `[ "$var" = "$value" ]` or `[[ "$var" == "$value" ]]`, *not* `[ "$var" == "$value" ]` -- as `[` is a POSIX-specified command, but [the spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) only specifies `=` as a string comparison operator, relying on `==` can lead to code that breaks when run with `/bin/sh`; by contrast, `[[` is explicitly nonportable, so using non-POSIX-compatible idioms there is less likely to lead to them leaking into code that's intended to be portable.

Comment: `INPUTS=$@` doesn't actually *work* correctly. Try it with a script, called like `./yourscript "first item" "second item"` -- `printf '%s\n' "$@"` will print `first item` and `second item` on two different lines as it should. By contrast, `INPUTS=$@` and then `printf '%s\n' $INPUTS` will print `first`, `item`, `second` and `item` as four different lines.

Comment: If you want to retain your original argument list, `inputs=( "$@" )` is correct syntax to do so; then you can iterate over `"${inputs[@]}"` later.

Comment: ...btw, note the use of lower-case variable names above; see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/style#variable_names, and http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html as a formal specification reserving all-caps names.

Comment: thatotherguy called out the problem, using `$()` creates subshells which means any changes to variables are lost when the subshell exits. The fundamental problem is that your *trying* to write in a structured style with functions, but you're relying on global variables. I'm not going to rewrite your code for you, but you have to break your dependence on global vars.